# Apache Bench: Why so many 503s?

Tags: php, linux, performance, apache, apachebench

I'm running a dedicated server on DreamHost: Quad Core, 4GB RAM.

Linux (Debian), Apache, PHP (with XCache for opcode caching), MySQL.

The URL I'm querying has 18 MySQL queries every time.

I'm wondering why when I do "ab -n 500 -c 50 http://<*url*>/" I'm getting the following results:

```
Server Software:        Apache
Server Hostname:        <url>
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        162809 bytes

Concurrency Level:      50
Time taken for tests:   12.664 seconds
Complete requests:      500
Failed requests:        377
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 377, Exceptions: 0)
Write errors:           0
Non-2xx responses:      377
Total transferred:      20291876 bytes
HTML transferred:       20147278 bytes
Requests per second:    39.48 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       1266.372 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       25.327 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          1564.81 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.4      0       2
Processing:   194 1190 1617.0    248    6060
Waiting:      194  965 1263.9    248    5190
Total:        194 1190 1617.0    248    6060

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    248
  66%    359
  75%   1555
  80%   2787
  90%   3979
  95%   4709
  98%   5427
  99%   5967
 100%   6060 (longest request)
```

All 377 failed requests are 503s.  What could be causing this?  Running `top` while doing this saw my processor spike to about 24%, but didn't tax it too much.

My CMS says that with a single load of the page, it takes .0017 seconds to load base classes, .1711 seconds for controller execution time, for a total execution time of .1731 seconds, using 2.887 MB of memory.

`ab -n 100 -c 10` always has 0 failed requests, but it seems that anything with concurrent connections over ~25 has a bunch of failed connections.

I'm expecting a ton of traffic next week all at once, how can I best prepare my server?  Will this hold up as is?

edit: from my httpd-mpm.conf file, which is included via httpd.conf

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          4
    MaxClients          600
    MinSpareThreads      50
    MaxSpareThreads      150
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Comment: 24% is 96% of one core.  Is it possible that you're running into issues making so many connections to the SQL server?  I'm assuming each hit on the apache server is causing 18 hits on the SQL server, is this correct?  Is the SQL server backend folding under the connections?

Comment: Can you post your apache `mpm worker` / `fcgid`/ `php-fpm` configurations parts? I'm suspecting that you simply run out of concurrently serviceable requests, since http 503 could simply mean that.

Comment: Maybe you setup your server with a limit to avoid flooding/DoS-attacks?

Comment: @Wug : Even running `ab -n 100 -c 30 http://<*url*>/phpinfo.php` (where there are no queries) resulted in 4 failed requests.

Comment: @complex857: I'm unfortunately not a server administrator, but this was tasked on me.   I know enough to get around, but I don't know exactly where those settings are configured.  Checked php.ini but didn't see anything.

Comment: @KingCrunch : I didn't explicitly set it up like that, and I can't tell if DreamHost does that by default or not

Comment: The very first important part is your apache mpm settings, at least show us that part.

Comment: @regilero : edited my first post to include mpm settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a DreamHost server and not a VPS, it's probably that they're killing your php processes because you've used up your slice of the CPU share. If one of your processes takes up too much resources or there are too many incoming connections, it'll get killed and the webserver will return a 503.

I have no idea what these limits are set to, but [someone from dreamhost explains in this thread](https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-120453.html):

> There is a limit of memory and connections your website can handle here on DH. If you are getting to many visitors which are using too many ressources you'll be getting 503 errors. Maybe your website has grown too big after three years? Without more information about the number of visitors and the used software we can only speculate.

Comment: I'm on a dedicated server, though.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by a few different things

1. Your webserver is hitting open file limit (check ulimit)
2. If you are using FPM you might be exceeding child limit (check fpm config)
3. You can be exceeding connection limit (check sysctl.conf)

First thing you should do is check the nginx or apache log.

Comment: Oh sorry I can see it's apache. I am almost sure you are using threaded model, so I think you should chech the config of mpm-worker, fast cgi or fpm